# How to increase docker memory limits with rancher desktop on MacOs?

Tags: docker, rancher, rancher-desktop

I'm using rancher desktop for docker on mac os and trying to run multiple containers with docker-compose. When I run couple of them, everything is ok, but when I run all of them, at least one container always ends up with OOM error(usually it's cassandra, but I think it just depends on start up order and memory consumption).

`docker stats` shows me that memory limit is 2.9GB. If I understand correctly, I have 2.9GB for all containers. And it's not enough for all of my containers.

I've tried to increase virtual machine memory in rancher desktop settings, gave it 17GB, but I still have only 2.9GB docker limit.

How can I increase available memory to docker with rancher desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is given in this issue:
https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/issues/2855

> On arm64 machines you will need to upgrade to Monterey 12.4 or later to use more than 3 GiB of memory for the virtual machine.